# Why does my dropdown menu just allow me to click the first item from the menu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu that allows me to navigate to different pages in my Web app. Every time I click on the menu, the items appear correctly but I can't seem to click on anything apart from the first item. They seem to be disabled.

Here are the images for how it looks for different items :
[image: First item]

[image: Second Item]

Both of them point to their respective pages, but the hyperlink only works on the first item. Am I missing something?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#"
         class="nav-link dropdown-toggle a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden"
         data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Characters</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="ron.html"
                 class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Ron</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="fatima.html"
                 class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Fatima</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="kandice.html" class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Kandice</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="ricky.html"
                 class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Ricky</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="rob.html" class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Rob</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example your problem is not cover, because in your code other elements have higher z-index than your drop-down.

z-index is property that specifies the z-order of an element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

from above explanation give `z-index: 1;` to your main parent div.

in this example parent is `li.nav-item`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#"
         class="nav-link dropdown-toggle a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden"
         data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Characters</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="ron.html"
                 class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Ron</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="fatima.html"
                 class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Fatima</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="kandice.html" class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Kandice</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="ricky.html"
                 class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Ricky</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="rob.html" class="nav-link a-btn ltc-gold-web-golden">Rob</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</li>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This might be a good answer if you explained _why_ setting `z-index: 1` solves the problem. As it is, it might solve the OP's problem, but it's not useful to future readers.